How to use "Product Icon Reference" for a WebView Icon?
There a several answers how to use icons for a WebView Tab in a VSCode Extension and all are using local files like of type .svg (vscode extension iconPath). I instead would like to use the VSCode icons from this website at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels. Is that possible and if yes, how ?
I tried to somehow use the icon syntax like in package.json as $(any-icon-identifier). But of course that is not possible for the webview.iconPath. I tried various conversations but without any success.

You cannot access any web content or resources from VS Code in your webview, except for what's available when you acquire the VS Code APIs.
However, it's easy to use the same images (without animation, though), because VS Code uses Codicon for all its little icons.
An example shows how to use Codicons in a webview. You have to install the codicon package:
npm i @vscode/codicons

Get the codicon CSS from that:
const codiconsUri = webview.asWebviewUri(vscode.Uri.joinPath(extensionUri, 'node_modules', '@vscode/codicons', 'dist', 'codicon.css'));

and then use CSS classes for HTML elements like div or span to show a codicon icon in them:
<div class="icon"><i class="codicon codicon-account"></i> account</div>

